# Creating VLAN 10 on OpenWRT v8 with TP-Link WR 841N freezes router

Tags: networking, openwrt

I just installed v8 of OpenWRT on a TP-Link WR841N and it worked. Now I'm trying to configure a VLAN for my WAN (optic router only provides it through a vlan) and I'm trying to set it up with VLAN 10 with CPU and Ether1 with tagged, all others untagged, and then setting the WAN to use the ether0.10 fron the VLAN. Every single time the router freezes and I have to reset it. How can I prevent it from freezing, or configuring it over another route (ssh maybe?) do it doesn't freeze?

Comment: Does it actually freeze, or are you losing connectivity to the router because of the network changes?

Comment: I tried to reconnect a couple of times and got time out every time.

Comment: Once you've lost connectivity because you've reconfigured the vlans (incorrectly) then that's quite permanent (until you reset the config obviously) so that's expected. I've done it myself: take the switch out of the bridge in order to add a vlan but you never get to add the vlan because once the bridging is removed you have no path to the cpu anymore. I now just edit /etc/config/network and reload the network after changing all I want to change.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post somewhere your config/network with vlans so I can take a look?

Comment: Sure, see http://pastebin.com/8UTgAHnX